# Rename columns in data frame using "arithmetic progression"

Tags: r, rename, multiple-columns

Suppose I've got the following `data.frame` composed of multiple rows (not all displayed here) and 31 columns. The first one is (and should remain) labelled "gene_ID" and, from the second all the way to the thirtieth column they have weird names, as follows:

```
 |gene_ID | weird1| weird2|all_the_way_to | weird30|
 |:-------|------:|------:|:--------------|-------:|
 |BPK282x |      4|      1|...            |       7|
 |BPK282y |      5|      2|...            |       8|
 |BPK282z |      6|      3|...            |       9|
```

I would like to rename all 30 columns names by a pattern like this: TPM_1, TPM_2, TPM_3, TPM_4.....TPM_30, resulting in the following table:

```
 |gene_ID | TPM_1| TPM_2|all_the_way_to | TPM_3|
 |:-------|-----:|-----:|:--------------|-----:|
 |BPK282x |     4|     1|...            |     7|
 |BPK282y |     5|     2|...            |     8|
 |BPK282z |     6|     3|...            |     9|
```

I could rename the columns individually by:

```
names(data.frame) <- c("gene_ID", "TPM_1", "TPM_2", "TPM_3", ..., "TPM_30")
```

yet I am wondering if there is a way to do automatize the process by using a function that would employ something like an arithmetic progression on the columns' names. In other words, I am trying to find a way to rename my columns with a pattern (TPM_followed by a number) in that the name of columns would be "TPM_n", "TPM_n+1", "TPM_n+2", TPM_n+3", all the way to "TPM_n+30"

Comment: @docendo discimus: Thanks for the editing. How do you paste tables from the R console that way? It does look way better...

Comment: Just copy and paste them into the question body, then select/highlight them and finally use the `{}` button at the top to indent all the highlighted text by 4 spaces. That way it's displayed properly

Comment: I was setting the code input manually with a ` at the beginning and another ` at the end of the table, but it is now working, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `paste0`

```
colnames(df) <- paste0("TPM_", 1:30)

#[1] "TPM_1"  "TPM_2"  "TPM_3"  "TPM_4"  "TPM_5"  "TPM_6"  "TPM_7"  "TPM_8" "TPM_9" 
#[10]"TPM_10" "TPM_11" "TPM_12" TPM_13" "TPM_14" "TPM_15" "TPM_16" "TPM_17" "TPM_18"
#[19]"TPM_19" TPM_20" "TPM_21" "TPM_22" "TPM_23" "TPM_24" "TPM_25" "TPM_26" "TPM_27"
#[28] "TPM_28" "TPM_29" "TPM_30"
```

You can always specify the indexes of the columns you want to change

```
colnames(df)[2:31] <- paste0("TPM_", 1:30)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `paste`.

```
colnames(df1)[-1] <- paste0("TPM_", head(seq_along(df1),-1))
colnames(df1)
#[1] "gene_ID" "TPM_1"   "TPM_2"
```

Here, we are naming only the 2nd to the last column.  The OP mentioned that the first column is "gene_ID".  Also, this is more general when the dataset is changed, we don't need to manually count 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. to check there is 30 columns or 100 ..

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(gene_ID = c("BPK282x", "BPK282y", "BPK282z"), 
weird1 = 4:6, weird2 = 1:3), .Names = c("gene_ID", "weird1", 
"weird2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste` to combine strings, and a numeric progression along the columns (e.g. `seq_along`). Using your required output in the standard `iris` dataset:

`names(iris) <- paste("TMP", seq_along(iris), sep = "_")`